# Can we analyse internal pages of a website using Google LIghthouse?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing, lighthouse

As an example, lets say I have a website and after user logged in using user credentials, a summary page is loading as a dashboard which has a large set of api calls and rendering. I want to get stats for the second page (summary page). Is there a way we can get that using google lighthouse? When I click generate the report when I'm inside the summary page it still gives the stats for the initial page, I mean login page. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use lighthouse [as a Node module](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/readme.md#using-programmatically) or via the [cli as described in the README](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/readme.md#testing-on-a-site-with-authentication). I typically use Puppeteer with lighthouse for this use case, similar to the [auth recipe](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/tree/master/docs/recipes/auth) example.